# How to compile gcc 32bit app on 64bit osx

Tags: c, macos, gcc

i try to compile a 32 bit app on my mac osx 64bit

I have a 32bit lib included.

I try to create a personal lib

> ```
> gcc -m32 -c fileA.c -Iinclude -o fileA.o
> gcc -m32 -c fileB.c -Iinclude -o fileB.o
> ```

All Ok

now I create .a File

> ```
> ar ruv ./lib/myLib.a fileA.o fileB.o
> ```

When I try to launch

> ```
> gcc -m32 -o imageMod imageMod.c -Iinclude -Llib
> ```

I receive the following error

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:   "_addozzo", referenced
>   from:
>         _main in imageMod-nfyyGP.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
>   (use -v to see invocation)

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell gcc to link in the library:

```
gcc -m32 -o imageMod imageMod.c -Iinclude -Llib -l:myLib.a
```

Comment: I try but now compiler return this error                            ld: library not found for -l:myLib.a
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)